# How to send and test a response from a Rest webservice in workbench

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, workbench

Is it possible to send a response message from a rest webservice? I have the following :

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/*')
 global with sharing class RestResource {
    @HttpGet
    webservice static List<Contact> showContact() {
        Boolean isValid;
        String phone; 
        List<Contact> resultCon= new List<Contact>();
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;

        try {
        phone = (request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)).replaceAll('[^0-9]','');
        isValid = Regex_Validator.isValidPhone(phone);
        system.debug('isValid '+ isValid);

            resultCon = [SELECT id, phone , lastname FROM Contact WHERE phone = :phone];
        } catch(exception e) {
            system.debug('Error'+ e);
        }
        system.debug(resultCon);
        if(resultCon.IsEmpty()) {
            response.statusCode = 204;
            response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            response.responseBody  = blob.valueOf('Sorry no match');
        }
        if(!isValid) {
            response.statusCode = 415;
            response.responseBody  = Blob.valueOf('Check format phonenumber :+00 0000000000');
        }
        if(!resultCon.IsEmpty()) {
            return resultCon;
        }else {
            return null;    
        }
    }
}
```

The statuscode is returned fine in workbench but the body is not!?

Comment: You haven't included enough context for your code to say with 100% certainty that you're not doing anything wrong, but it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong here. The responseBody should be getting sent back in the response to your webservice being called. What makes you think that it isn't being sent back? Where have you looked? Is there any other code in the execution path that messes with your response? Have you tried adding debugs to your code and looking at the logs?

Comment: @DerekF I added my complete code to give it more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change variable  response.responseBody to RestContext.response.responseBody and also set the Content-Type, see below image: if it helps? I tried and it works fine:

[image]

It provides the response text:

[image]

Comment: A code block is more appropriate for multi-line snippets, but that still makes this answer a code dump. I can see what the difference is, but you should edit this answer to explain, using words, what the difference between your code and OP's code is. Also, it would be good to explain _why_ you think this should work.

Comment: It should, now.